# Error Status 500 en java

Tags: java, utf-8

Me sale el siguiente error de UTF-8 cuando abro la vista de HTML:

> HTTP Status 500 - type Exception report
>
> message
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException:
>   Exception thrown in state 'adminPlanManejo' of flow 'adminPlanManejo'
>   root cause
>
> org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException:
>   Exception thrown in state 'adminPlanManejo' of flow 'adminPlanManejo'
>   root cause
>
> javax.faces.FacesException:
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:
>   Byte no válido 2 de la secuencia UTF-8 de 4 bytes root cause
>
> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:
>   Byte no válido 2 de la secuencia UTF-8 de 4 bytes note The full stack
>   traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the
>   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.

Si alguien sabe qué es y cómo solucionarlo les agradezco, ya que he intentado de varias formas solucionarlo y no he podido. De ante mano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar **utf-8** para todo el proyecto puedes agregarlo en `web.xml`

de esta manera:

```
<filter>  
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
<init-param>  
   <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
</init-param>  
<init-param>  
<param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
 <param-value>true</param-value>  
</init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

O si usaras `maven` puedes hacerlo de esta manera en el `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```